# angularJS .push inserts empty row

Tags: angularjs

The `.push` in my `success` function doesn't work: It adds an empty row to the list.

js:

```
$scope.ajouterIngredient = function(){
        if (!$scope.nomi || $scope.nomi ==='') { return; }
        recettes.addingredient(recette._id,{
            nomi: $scope.nomi,
            nombre: $scope.nombre
            }).success(function(ingredient){
                $scope.recette.ingredients.push(ingredient);
        });
```

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ingredient in recette.ingredients | orderBy:'-nombre'">
          <td> {{ingredient.nombre}}</td>
          <td> {{ingredient.nomi}}</td>
          </tr>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is happening, and how is it different from what you expect? Is there any console output? What do the contents of `ingredient` look like? My guess is that the `ingredient` parameter in your success function is actually a wrapper object that holds the data you actually want to push. Also, in general, you should be using `then()` instead of `success()/error()` for all promises.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
What is happening is that when I add something with my form, the addingredient function work well (it populate my mongo DB) . and a new row appear at the begining of the table. But that row is empty. And when I refresh the page, the table is good.

nothing in the console. The contents of ingredient is like this:
{"_id":"5859b5028a49aa49b4623930","recette":"5859b4fc8a49aa49b462392f","nomi":"fake","nombre":5,"__v":0

I think that your guess is good! the ingredient is actyal